# jQuery dynamic image loading

Tags: jquery, image, input, loading, fadein

**I try to load an image when I type a reference in an input.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#id').focus();
                $('#id').keyup(function () {
                    $('#img').html('<img src="http://www.site.com/' + $(this).val() + '.jpg"
    width="200px">');
                    $('#img').hide().fadeIn('slow');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" size="7" maxlength="7" id="id">
        <div id="img"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

The fadeIn() doesn't work, except if the image is already in cache. How can I have a fadeIn each time? Thanx in advance.

**EDIT**

Another script, it works!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#id').focus();
                $('#id').keyup(function () {
                    $('#img').attr('src', 'http://www.site.com/' + $(this).val() + '.jpg');
                    $('#img').hide();
                });
                $('#img').load(function () {
                    $('#img').fadeIn('slow');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" size="7" maxlength="7" id="id">
        <br>
        <img id="img" width="200px">
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: The fadeIn DOES work, you just aren't giving it anything TO fade in because the image isn't loaded yet. You need to pre-load the image.

Comment: I don't see a problem with it: http://jsfiddle.net/JTJKd/2/

Comment: @Chad I think there's no problem with Google images as they are very small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go ahead and cache the image (pre-load it into a variable) so that you can access it quickly. You also might want to make use of jQuery's [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) function to tell you when the image has been loaded. Here's a quick example:

```
var theCachedImage = new Image();
/* Boolean that tells us whether or not the image has finished loading. */
var theBoolean;
$(theCachedImage).load(function () {
    In this callback, the image has finished loading.Set "theBoolean"
    to true.
    theBoolean = true;
});
theCachedImage.src = "your/image/source";
```

Like Kevin mentioned, the fadeIn is working. There's just nothing to fade in.

**EDIT:**

In your `keyUp` function, simply check the value of the conditional boolean and perform actions accordingly. Example:

```
$('#id').keyup(function () {
    if (theBoolean) {
        $('#img').html('<img src="http://www.site.com/' + $(this).val() + '.jpg"
width="200px">');
        $('#img').hide().fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        /* Your image hasn't been loaded yet. Do something to let the user know
         * or figure out the appropriate action to take. */
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanx, but I don't know how to use the load() function with the keyup() one.

Comment: Thanx for your efforts, I updated my script and it works now!

Comment: Can i load images dynamically, with huge no.of images. Like i have 200 images, and i have to show images on slide show, can i load images in a set of 10 images per set???

Comment: Hmmm... it really depends on what you're trying to do. If you create a new question and provide some more details on what exactly you're trying to do, I'd be happy to help you out. Just post a link here so that I know that you created it.