# How to escape html tags and show it in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

The `test.php` read the database , and prepare it in JSON format.
then `test.html` callback the data and show it in the table.

`test.php`.

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "xxxx", "guestbook"); 
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT title, content, author, email, ip FROM lyb where  title="test"');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($title, $content, $author, $email, $ip);
$result = [];
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $result[] = [
        'title'   => $title,
        'content' => $content,
        'author'  => $author,
        'email'   => $email,
        'ip'      => $ip
    ];
}
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Now to test the `test.php` with `php -f  test.php`.

```
[{"title":"test","content":"<p><img alt=\"\" src=\"upfiles\/54591303758197437.jpg\" \/><\/p>","author":"me","email":"me@tom.com","ip":"111.111.111.111"}]
```

Notice :the value of content contains html tags,i want to show it on webpage.

`test.html` file callback `test.php` and show data on webpage.

```
<h2 align="center">Ajax show data in table</h2>
<table border="2">
    <tbody id="disp">
        <th>title</th>
        <th>content</th>
        <th>author</th>
        <th>email</th>
        <th>ip</th>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script> 
$(function(){
    $.getJSON("test.php", function(data) {
        $.each(data,function(i,item){
            var tr = "<tr><td>" + item.title + "</td>" +
                        "<td>"  + item.content  + "</td>" +
                        "<td>"  + item.author  + "</td>" +
                        "<td>"  + item.email  + "</td>"  +
                        "<td>"  + item.ip  + "</td></tr>"
            $("#disp").append(tr);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

What i get is as below:

```
<h2 align="center">Ajax show data in table</h2>
<table border="2">
    <tbody id="disp">
        <th>title</th>
        <th>content</th>
        <th>author</th>
        <th>email</th>
        <th>ip</th>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>me</td>
            <td>me@tom.com</td>
            <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Type `127.0.0.1/test.html` , all the tags and values of content`<p><img alt=\"\" src=\"upfiles\/54591303758197437.jpg\" \/><\/p>"` lost.
How to show the content `<p><img alt="" src="upfiles/54591303758197437.jpg" /></p>"` containing no escape character `\`, instead of losing it ,and instead of strings containing escapge character `\`?

I expect to show as below :

```
<h2 align="center">Ajax show data in table</h2>
<table border="2">
    <tbody id="disp">
        <th>title</th>
        <th>content</th>
        <th>author</th>
        <th>email</th>
        <th>ip</th>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>&ltp&gt;&lt;img alt="" src="upfiles/54591303758197437.jpg" /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</td>
            <td>me</td>
            <td>me@tom.com</td>
            <td>111.111.111.111</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML-encoding lost when attribute read from input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-lost-when-attribute-read-from-input-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a issue to convert string containning  escape character into raw html inner string.

Keep other code snippet unchanged.

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON("test-json.php", function(data) {
        $.each(data,function(i,item){
            alert(item.content);
            var tr = "<tr><td>" + item.title + "</td>" +
                        "<td>"  + $('<div/>').text(item.content).html() + "</td>" +
                        "<td>"  + item.author  + "</td>" +
                        "<td>"  + item.email  + "</td>"  +
                        "<td>"  + item.ip  + "</td></tr>"
            $("#disp").append(tr);
        });
    });
});
```

The core concept is create a virtual jquery html containner,then text(target-string).html().

```
$('<div/>').text(item.content).html()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code working fine. When I inspected the DOM, the content is there but the image is not displayed. You can check this by changing the background color or adding some text inside your `<p></p>`.

To display the image, you should probably load it, before displaying it. You could have a look at this:
[jQuery dynamic image loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518758/jquery-dynamic-image-loading)

Since you actually whant to display the html you should escape it. You can do it in php: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlspecialchars.asp